# What are Azure Relay service throttling limits?

Tags: azure, azure-relay

How throttling is defined for the [Azure Fluid Relay](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/fluid-relay)?

I cannot find it anywhere.
We are implementing a pilot to switch our app to the Azure-Relay service. Unfortunately, even with a minimal user load we run into "throttling" error, i.e. 429.

Meaning, the fluid websocket connection is full of messages like the one below, and the connection does not seem to work properly at all:

```
{
  "message": "Throttling count exceeded by 1066 at 2023-03-XXXXX",
  "retryAfter": 31,
  "code": 429,
  "type": "ThrottlingError"
}
```

So, what are the throttling limits, are they defined per tenant, or per what? In our case, it looks like using one application affects other relay applications as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are limits on:

- Sessions = 100 users
- Operations = 700 KB
- Summaries = 28 MB

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-fluid-relay/reference/service-limits

If you are getting this error at a low load it may be that the individual payload is too large.

Comment: What is "individual payload"? I started getting it today (or maybe yesterday), before (for about two months) it was fine. I.e. now it just occurs for any connection, just sending 100 bytes change causes it. I'm looking at the ws (websocket) connection, on the API level it looks like timeout that never ends. Also, these are SIZE limits from the docs, I'm looking for THROTTLING limits.

Comment: Also, is this a rate limit per tenant, or per service in the tenant, or per user? I'm looking for some documentation for Azure Relay similar to graph throttling limits, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits

Comment: Maybe the Azure Fluid Relay is just down (or overloaded?) in my region? Is there a service health check page? The application sends like than 1 request per second, changest size 100 bytes, and still gets throttled??